# jQuery autocomplete update results number

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I trying to do a autocomplete with jQuery Ui that show a numbers of results real time.

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/DZ9zU/1/):

```
$(function () {
    var projects = [{
        value: "jquery",
        label: "jQuery",
        desc: "the write less, do more, JavaScript library",
        icon: "jquery_32x32.png"
    }, {
        value: "jquery-ui",
        label: "jQuery UI",
        desc: "the official user interface library for jQuery",
        icon: "jqueryui_32x32.png"
    }, {
        value: "sizzlejs",
        label: "Sizzle JS",
        desc: "a pure-JavaScript CSS selector engine",
        icon: "sizzlejs_32x32.png"
    }];

    $("#project").autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: projects,
        response: function (event, ui) {
            var len = ui.content.length;
            $('#count').html('Founded ' + len + ' results');
        }
    });
});
```

but applied on my more complex script [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wolfovs/5kmgqctb/3/).

Does someone knows how to integrate?
Thanks so much.

Comment: Not sure what your question is here. Both your fiddles work. What are you having trouble with?

Comment: Hey thanks to formatted my question :) The issue is that miss a counter that inform how many resoults there.